# AD Authentication using LDAP : Can I authenticate outside of DMZ/Domain

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap

The method I use to authenticate a user's credentials on active directory is (Simplified):

```
New DirectorySearcher(New DirectoryEntry(path, user, pass, AuthenticationTypes.Secure)).FindOne()
```

On fail, the LDAP object could not be created, thus the username, password, or path is invalid.

This works on my current domain which happens to correspond with the ldap connection string (path above).

What is the scope of this authentication: will it work outside of the domain or dmz?